# Similar way adding 2d array in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I want to add data into my array similar way as this C++ code.

```
String a[3][4] = {  
    {"Burger", "6", "b", "u"} ,   /*  initializers for row indexed by 0 */
    {"Pizza", "5", "p", "z"} ,   /*  initializers for row indexed by 1 */
    {"Kebab", "4", "k", "b"}   /*  initializers for row indexed by 2 */
};
```

In objective-C, my attempt.

```
NSString *a[10][20] = {
    {@"Burger", @"6", @"b", @"u"} ,   /*  initializers for row indexed by 0 */
    {@"Pizza", @"5", @"p", @"z"} ,   /*  initializers for row indexed by 1 */
    {@"Kebab", @"4", @"k", @"b"}   /*  initializers for row indexed by 2 */
};
```

I am not sure if above example works, I will test it once I access to a MAC.

**My question is:**

What is the right way of doing it, perhaps the best way.

And will my Objective-C code work?

I apologize for asking this question without testing it due to no-access to a MAC.

Comment: So you posted a question without actually trying it first? Why?

Comment: I already stated that I don't have access to Xcode at the moment. And I need to hardcode huge amount of data right now..

Comment: How much data? It may be better to put the data in a plist file or a database. Hardcoding so many string literals into the code isn't the best option. And you might also wish to use an array of dictionaries. It will make your data a lot more flexible.

Comment: @rmaddy About 100 rows, that will NEVER be changed. Each row will have different amount of columns, so I don't think database will be a good option. But I will surely check out plist and array of dictionary which I assume is NSmutableDictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Objective-C you want to declare a like this:

```
NSArray *a = @[
    @[@"Burger", @"6", @"b",@"u"] ,   /*  initializers for row indexed by 0 */
    @[@"Pizza", @"5", @"p", @"z" ] ,   /*  initializers for row indexed by 1 */
    @[@"Kebab", @"4", @"k", @"b"]   /*  initializers for row indexed by 2 */
];
```

Then you can index into a to get each array like this:

```
NSArray *firstArray = a[0];
```

Comment: This will be very inconvenient when I have 30+ rows. Is there a easier way where I can access it like `[][]`? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Alice Why do you think this syntax is very inconvenient compares to the C-array syntax?

Comment: @Alice If I follow your question, then yep you can say `NSString *p = a[1][2];`

Comment: @rmaddy Let's say I want to pick a random word from my Array. with `[][]` I can go: `randomWord = arc4random() % 30;` assuming I have 30 rows, this will pick one random row for me. With what @carl suggested I have no idea how to do that. That would be more like picking a random Array instead of a random index.

Comment: @Alice Actually there is no difference. In both cases you need to pass two indexes. The 1st gives the row and the 2nd gives the element in that row.

Comment: @Alice couldn't you use two random indices then? `randomRow = arc4random() % 30` and `randomIndex = arc4random() % 4`?

Comment: @Carl.Hinkle and @rmaddy sorry for the confusion. Basically I can go `a[2][0]` and it will give me `Pizza`? For some reason I thought I had to make a new array for each row. My apologizes. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: a[2][0] would give you Kebob, but I think you have the idea now.

Comment: @Carl.Hinkle Exactly! I'm just too exhausted. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Using Objective-Cs literal syntax for an array with 3 arrays containing NSStrings:

```
NSArray *a = @[
               @[@"Burger", @"6", @"b", @"u"],
               @[@"Pizza", @"5", @"p", @"z"],
               @[@"Kebab", @"4", @"k", @"b"]
              ];
```

Comment: This creates `NSArray` with `NSArray`. That's not the same as creating a C-array.

Comment: True, though it may serve the purpose to the person asking the question as the question says similar to a C-array.

Comment: The question is similar to a C++ C-array. Objective-C is a superset of C so it also supports C-arrays.